# Error "64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded"

Tags: python, oracle

I know this question has been asked several times, but I've spent all afternoon trying all of the suggestions listed in the other answers to no avail. I'm hoping someone can help me figure out what I'm missing.

I'm trying to install and run cx_Oracle. I'm  using Python 3.6 and Anaconda 4.4 through the Spyder IDE, running on Windows 7.

Here's what I tried:

1. Following [this link](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows) I downloaded the Visual Studio redistributable and ran the executable. Everything seemed to be fine.
2. From [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html) I downloaded the .zip file for the 64-bit Oracle instant client. I unzipped the link to the folder **C:\ORACLE\instantclient_12_2\instantclient_12_2** (it was an accident that it was repeated twice like that, but it shouldn't matter).
3. I added this folder to my path. I actually ended up adding it in several places when I couldn't get things to work (you know what they say, "desperation is the mother of invention"). It ended up in my **PATH** variable, as a new System variable **ORACLE_HOME**, and as a new User variable, also **ORACLE_HOME**. I also removed an older distribution of an Oracle client from the **PATH**.
4. Finally, I installed cx_Oracle from the command line using `python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade --pre`

As I understand it, this should have worked. My internet research revealed that the biggest problem here is that people have different architectures installed, so I checked to make sure everything was the same. I redownloaded and reinstalled the VS redistributable and Instant Client, making sure both are 64-bit. I checked my python size using `sys.maxsize > 2**32` and received a True response, making me think I have the right version there. Finally, I assumed that pip would automatically get the 64-bit version of cx_Oracle based on other comments online.

When I go to run the program the **import cx_Oracle** runs just fine. However, my connection doesn't work:

`connection = cx_Oracle.connect(CPR_ID+'/'+CPR_PW + '@' + CPR_SRV)`

I then get the common error:

`DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "%1 is not a valid Win32 application". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help`

I of course followed the link and tried the steps there but that didn't help. I know that the variables in the command are all defined. That's certainly not the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Again, sorry for the dupe, but none of the other steps I've found seem to be working for me.

Comment: Is your python actually 64bit? `python` into the interactive mode to find out, you should see something like: `Python ... [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`. Also, use `os.environ['ORACLE_HOME']` to see if it's actually set properly to python interpreter.

Comment: Yes, python is actually 64-bit. When I run that command I get: `Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)...[MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32.`

Comment: When I try the `os.environ` command I also get the expected result: `C:\\ORACLE\\instantclient_12_2\\instantclient_12_2`

Comment: Perhaps Anaconda is doing something funky with paths still. The error you're getting is usually an exe loading problem involving 64-vs-32bit. Have you tried installing cxOracle via `conda` instead of `pip` (make sure to pip uninstall first)?

Comment: Try to add also `C:\ORACLE\instantclient_12_2\instantclient_12_2\bin` to your `PATH` variable. Check entries in Registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient12_home1` (or similar)

Comment: Make sure you have the appropriate VS Redistributable installed - see the Instant Client download page for which one to use for each Instant Client version.

Comment: Thank you @ChristopherJones! That was it! I had downloaded a too recent version of the VS Redistributable.